# Skyscraper sheaf on a stack associated to a singular surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, resolution-of-singularities, algebraic-stacks

Suppose $X$ is a normal projective surface with a du Val singularity. In this case, we know a crepant resolution $Y$ exists, and results of Kawamata (https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.3150, Corollary 3.5) show that there is an equivalence $$ \phi: D^b(\text{Coh}(\mathcal X)) \simeq D^b(\text{Coh}(Y)) $$
where $\mathcal X$ is the smooth DM stack associated to $X$.

Let $k(p)$ be the skyscraper sheaf over a singular point $p$ of $X$. One knows that $k(p)$ does not have a finite free resolution by $\mathcal O_X$-modules, so $k(p)\notin D^b(\text{Coh}(X))$. My question is then two-fold:

First: the sheaf $k(p)$ can also be regarded as a sheaf on the stack $\mathcal X$. Is that correct? Does it have a finite resolution by free $\mathcal O_{\mathcal X}$-modules? How is this resolution constructed?

Second: if $k(p)\in D^b(\text{Coh}(X))$, what is its image under the equivalence $\phi$?

More in general, is there a geometric picture one should have in mind when comparing $X$ and its stack $\mathcal X$, to help intuition?

Comment: The fact that $k(p)$ does not have a finite free resolution means that $k(p)$ is not a perfect complex. But it is an object of $D^b(Coh(X))$.

Comment: A good example to look at is the case of $X$ being a quadratic cone. Then $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{A}^2/\mu_2$ (the quotient stack), where $\mu_2$ acts on $\mathbb{A}^2$ by $-1$. Note that there are two "point objects" over $k(p)$ provided by the structure sheaf of the origin with the two different $\mu_2$-equivariant structures.